# Reliable sources for society trust score?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, cross-cultural-psychology, altruism, trust

It seems like that the **general public** [1,2,3] and some academics [4,5] **believe** that **China is** an exemplar **society of low-trust**. Most of my friends share the same beliefs. However, one **data source claims that China has the highest social trust** score: https://ourworldindata.org/trust. See also: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9248.2011.00909.x.

From my limited experience, people in China don't trust commercials, agents, or anyone who wants your money; but commoners are often trustable.

I tried to find several academic papers [6,7,8,9] but none of them directly compare the trust level in China and a Western country.

Do you have some **reliable reference**?

---

[1]https://www.thenationalnews.com/arts-culture/china-has-a-high-yield-but-low-trust-society-says-author-of-age-of-ambition-1.321115

[2]https://asiasociety.org/switzerland/social-credit-scores-low-trust-society

[3]https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseHistory/comments/86vss4/has_china_always_been_a_low_trust_society/

[4]https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_gUmC7iCfiAJ:https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/low-trust-societies-can-only-thrive-under-authoritarian-governments+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca

[5]https://www.jstor.org/stable/26384944?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

[6]https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0095555

[7]https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/39972/wp586.pdf?sequence=3

[8]https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12939-016-0469-7

[9]http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-JJYJ200210007.htm